# Array is cleared after exiting OvserveEventType closure in Firebase/Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase

I have a database with this structure:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "8eee4af2-7a02-4c5c-9c2a-5a50623bd681" : {
      "menu" : {
        "-KHG5aYVJM4iDQqA0EQS" : {
          "itemDescription" : "Description 1",
          "itemName" : "Item 1",
          "itemPrice" : "Price 1"
        },
        "-KHG5eJUAUbtXZLEF2Fb" : {
          "itemDescription" : "Description 2",
          "itemName" : "Item 2",
          "itemPrice" : "Price 2"
        },
        "-KHG5hsYhJTrzbqBUPOO" : {
          "itemDescription" : "Description 3",
          "itemName" : "Item 3",
          "itemPrice" : "Price 3"
        },
        "-KHG5lDw-uQXrKobPDlC" : {
          "itemDescription" : "Description 4",
          "itemName" : "Item 4",
          "itemPrice" : "Price 4"
        },
      },
    },
  },
},
```

I am trying to place the itemNames in an array, to be used later in a table.  However, it seems to clear my entire array once it exits the observeEventType enclosure. I've placed some print() statements throughout the loop, and found that I can get it to print the array as it appends if the statement is directly beneath the appending code, but outside the }), it only returns an empty array.

```
    let menuItems = ref.childByAppendingPath("users/\(ref.authData.uid)/menu")
    menuItems.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        for id in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FDataSnapshot] {


            let itemName = ref.childByAppendingPath("users/\(ref.authData.uid)/menu/\(id.key)/itemName")
            itemName.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock:{ snapshot in

                self.itemNames.append(snapshot.value as! String)
                print(self.itemNames)
                //This print returns an array full of itemNames

            })

          print(self.itemNames)
          //This print returns nil
        }

    })
```

Can anyone tell me what's happening / how to fix it?

Comment: The itemNames are already in the values returned with menuItems. You iterate over the snapshot and each id will be a separate child that you can get the name from  let name = id.value["itemName"]. Why is there another observe needed inside the first block?

Comment: Hmm, so I replaced my internal observe with name = id.value["itemName"].
It still is clearing when I exit the block though.

Comment: Here is how my arrays are set up:

var itemNames:[String] = []
var itemPrices:[String] = []
var itemDescriptions:[String] = []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!  Code updated with @jay's answer is below, all I had to do was tell the table to reload data before exiting the loop.

```
let menuItems = ref.childByAppendingPath("users/\(ref.authData.uid)/menu")
    menuItems.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        //each time I reload this data after submitting a new menu item, I have to clear itemNames, otherwise it adds duplicate items.
        self.itemNames = [String]()
        self.itemPrices = [String]()
        self.itemDescriptions = [String]()

        for id in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FDataSnapshot] {

            let name = id.value["itemName"] as! String
            self.itemNames.append(name)

            let price = id.value["itemPrice"] as! String
            self.itemPrices.append(price)

            let description = id.value["itemDescription"] as! String
            self.itemDescriptions.append(description)



        }

        //Solution below.  MenuTable is the table all of this is being displayed in
        ******self.menuTable.reloadData()********

    })
```